# How to add conditional sum aggregate column to SQL query which depends on preceding rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Assume I have following table

```
|Id|Debtor|Creditor|
| 0|0     |400     |
| 1|1000  |0       |
| 2|2000  |0       |
| 3|0     |5000    |
```

I need to add two columns `TotalDebt` and `TotalCredit` on each row with a condition that in a single row only one of totals is filled and the other one is zero.
Here is the query result I'm looking for.

```
|Id|Debtor|Creditor|TotalDebt|TotalCredit|
| 0|0     |400     |0        |400        |
| 1|1000  |0       |600      |0          |
| 2|2000  |0       |2600     |0          |
| 3|0     |5000    |0        |2400       |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

Create and populate sample data (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    id int,
    Debtor int,
    Creditor int
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(0, 0   , 400 ),
(1, 1000, 0   ),
(2, 2000, 0   ),
(3, 0   , 5000)
```

Use a cte for a rolling sum of both the Debtor and Creditor columns:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  id, 
            Debtor, 
            Creditor, 
            SUM(Creditor - Debtor) OVER(ORDER BY ID) As RollingSum
    FROM @T
)
```

Select from the cte:

```
SELECT  Id,
        Debtor,
        Creditor,
        IIF(RollingSum < 0, -RollingSum, 0) As TotalDebt,
        IIF(RollingSum > 0, RollingSum, 0) As TotalCredit
FROM CTE
```

Results:

```
Id  Debtor  Creditor    TotalDebt   TotalCredit
0   0       400         0           400
1   1000    0           600         0
2   2000    0           2600        0
3   0       5000        0           2400
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/ZLV50748)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, Debtor, Creditor, 
       IIF(Debtor=0, 0, SUM(Debtor-Creditor) OVER (ORDER BY Id)) AS TotalDebt,
       IIF(Creditor=0, 0, SUM(Creditor-DEbtor) OVER (ORDER BY Id)) AS TotalCredit
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/VHJCB23628)

Comment: What if you add this row: `4, 100, 0`? Your result would show `-2300` in the `TotalDebt` column and `0` in the `TotalCredit`column... http://rextester.com/RDCQT51162

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think this is what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Well, a total debt of -2300 is in fact a total credit of 2300, which is what my suggestion would show. I guess we will have to wait fo the OP to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *,
       case when [Debtor]> 0 then sum([Debtor] - [Creditor] ) over (order by id) 
            else 0 end as TotalDebt,
       case when [Creditor]> 0 then sum([Creditor] - [Debtor]) over (order by id) 
            else 0 end as TotalCredit
FROM table1
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/HQCZQH39439

Answer (score 0):

Use Subqueries for computation the sum for all entries lower than or equal to the given "Id"

Answer (score 0):

Below query will work for you if you do not want to use IIF (this is version specific), try below query this will give you the exact required output :

```
DECLARE @TableData AS TABLE(id int,Debtor int,Creditor int)

INSERT INTO @TableData VALUES
(0, 0, 400 ),
(1, 1000, 0),
(2, 2000, 0),
(3, 0, 5000),
(4, 10, 0),
(5, 0, 20)

;WITH SAMPLEDATA
AS
(
    SELECT *,0 TD,Creditor TC FROM @TableData WHERE ID=0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T2.*,
    CASE WHEN T2.Debtor=0 THEN 0 ELSE T1.TD+(T2.Debtor-T1.Creditor) END,
    CASE WHEN T2.Creditor=0 THEN 0 ELSE T2.Creditor-T1.TD END
     FROM SAMPLEDATA T1 JOIN @TableData T2 ON T1.id=T2.id-1 
)
select * from SAMPLEDATA
```

Output of query, with some additional dummy data :

```
---------------------------------
id  Debtor  Creditor    TD  TC
---------------------------------
0   0       400     0       400
1   1000    0       600     0
2   2000    0       2600    0
3   0       5000    0       2400
4   10      0       -4990   0
5   0       20      0       5010
---------------------------------
```